# Show posts from a custom taxonomy on a page

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to show my portfolios by category (i have 3 categories) On Dashboard i can create new categories/types but when i want list only **"design category"** on portfolio page "content not found"

these codes in function.php

```
function portfolio_s (){
    $labels = array(

    'name' => 'Portfolio',
    'singular_name'=>'Portfolio',
    'add_new' => 'Add Item',
    'all_items' => 'all Item',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add new Item',
    'edit_item' => 'edit Item',
    'new_item' => 'new Item',
    'view_item' => 'view Item',
    'search_item' => 'search Item',
    'not_found' => 'No Items found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No item',
    'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Item',
    );

    $args=array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'publicly_gueryable' =>true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'supports' => array(
    'title',
    'editor',
    'excerpt',
    'thumbnail',
    'revisions',
    ),

    'exclude_from_search' => false
);
register_post_type( "portfolio", $args );
} 
add_action( 'init', 'portfolio_s' );

function portfolio_taxonomies() {

    $labels = array(
    'name' => 'Types',
    'singular_name' => 'Type',
    'search_items' => 'Search Types',
    'all_items' => 'All Types',
    'parent_item' => 'Parent Types',
    'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Types',
    'edit_item' => 'edit Type',
    'update_item' => 'update Type',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add new Product',
    'new_item_name' => 'All Types',
    'menu_name' => 'Types',
    );

    $args= array(
    'hierarchical'          => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' =>true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'type')

    );
    register_taxonomy('type', array('portfolio'), $args);
    }
    add_action('init', 'portfolio_taxonomies');
```

portfolio file here.

```
<div class="row">

<?php   $query = new WP_Query( array( 'slug' => 'design' ) );?>

<?php if($query->have_posts()):?>   

<?php while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();?>   




            <div class="col-md-3 referans-oge">

            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail-large', array('class'=>'img-fluid'));?></a>



            </div>

<?php endwhile;?>       

<?php else:?>

Content not found

<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of your code looks OK. But there is a major problem with your WP_Query in portfolio template. Your query looks like this:

```
<?php   $query = new WP_Query( array( 'slug' => 'design' ) );?>
```

And if you take a look at [WP_Query docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), you'll see there is no parameter called `slug`. So it's pretty clear that it can't work.

If you want to display `portfolio` posts with given `type`, then your query should look like this:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array( 'taxonomy' => 'type', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'design' ),
    ),
) );
```